# Buffer-cum-Level shifter using dual MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, level-shifting, buffer

I am putting together a Buffer-cum-Level shifter using dual MOSFET to deal with PWM signal for display backlight control.

This 3.3V PWM signal is driven by MSP430G2452 and would be reaching the panel through cable. I want this MOSFET to serve two purpose

- Act as level shifter (convert 3.3V PWM to 5V PWM) if R3 is mounted.
  Reason is some panels need 5V PWM.
- Act as buffer / voltage follower if R4 is mounted.

Please help me with the following

1. What are the electrical specifications (thresholds) to be met for both modes of operation mentioned above?
2. Are there any mistakes on my circuit? Can 3.3V be switched using 3.3V and is FDC6327C the right choice?

[image]

Comment: why are you using second PMOSFET? I think, the conversion is possible using only one MOSFET

Comment: What type of drive strength does your output (the input to the display backlight) need? Right now your output has a low impedance (good drive strength) when it is outputting HIGH, but when outputting a LOW signal it has a 10k impedance, which is a pretty weak drive strength. Is this sufficient for your application?

Comment: @Umar Using dual FET to avoid any changes in firmware, usage of just N MOSFET will invert the signal.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub Good point. I can tweak the resistor value after testing. Is there anything else to be taken care of?